# Replicating GL intermediate mode lighting model in GLSL

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, lighting

So, I'm now at the stage where my head is spinning....

What I'm attempting to do is to recreate an existing intermediate mode lighting engine in GLSL.

Intermediate mode is dead simple when it comes down to it, only ambient and a single directional light like so:

```
GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, new[] { (float)Lighting.OptionLightPosition.X, (float)Lighting.OptionLightPosition.Y, (float)-Lighting.OptionLightPosition.Z, 0.0f });
GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Ambient,new Color4(OptionAmbientColor.R,OptionAmbientColor.G,OptionAmbientColor.B,255));
GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Diffuse, new Color4(OptionDiffuseColor.R, OptionDiffuseColor.G, OptionDiffuseColor.B, 255));
GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelAmbient, new[] { (float)LightModel.X, (float)LightModel.Y, (float)LightModel.Z, (float)LightModel.W });
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0);
```

I don't think anything else is necessarily relevant at this point, as it's the directional light that I can't get to play ball properly.
The only (minor) gotcha is that the Z-coordinates are reversed.

After a lot of false starts, I've got the following GLSL vertex shader, which is adapted from code from here https://github.com/mojocorp/ShaderGen

This looks decent under most circumstances, and is the closest I've managed to get, but it isn't right at all.

```
#version 150
precision highp int;
struct Light
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    vec4 lightModel;
};

struct MaterialColor
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec3 emission;
    float shininess;
}; 

in vec3 iPosition;
in vec3 iNormal;
in vec2 iUv;
in vec4 iColor;

uniform mat4 uCurrentProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 uCurrentModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uCurrentTextureMatrix;

uniform bool uIsLight;
uniform Light uLight;
uniform MaterialColor uMaterial;
uniform int uMaterialFlags;

out vec4 oViewPos;
out vec2 oUv;
out vec4 oColor;
out vec4 lightResult;


//Temp working colors
vec4 Ambient;
vec4 Diffuse;
vec4 Specular;

void findDirectionalLight(in vec3 normal)
{
   float pf;
   float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(normal, normalize(vec3 (uLight.position))));
   float nDotHV = max(0.0, dot(normal, normalize(vec3(oViewPos.xyz + uLight.position))));

   if (nDotVP == 0.0)
   {
       pf = 0.0;
   }
   else
   {
       pf = pow(nDotHV, uMaterial.shininess);
   }

   Ambient  += vec4(uLight.ambient, 1.0);
   Diffuse  += vec4(uLight.diffuse, 1.0) * nDotVP;
   Specular += vec4(uLight.specular, 1.0) * pf;
}

vec4 getLightResult(in vec3 normal, in vec4 ecPosition)
{
    vec4 color;
    vec3 ecPosition3;
    vec3 eye;

    ecPosition3 = (vec3 (ecPosition)) / ecPosition.w;
    eye = vec3 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    Ambient  = vec4 (0.0);
    Diffuse  = vec4 (0.0);
    Specular = vec4 (0.0);

    findDirectionalLight(normal);
    vec4 sceneColor = uLight.lightModel;
    if((uMaterialFlags & 1) != 0)
    {
        sceneColor = vec4(uMaterial.emission, 1.0) + uMaterial.ambient * uLight.lightModel;
    }
    color = sceneColor + Ambient  * uMaterial.ambient + Diffuse  * uMaterial.specular;
    color += Specular * uMaterial.specular;
    color = clamp(color, 0.0, 1.0);
    return color;
}


void main()
{
    oViewPos = uCurrentModelViewMatrix * vec4(vec3(iPosition.x, iPosition.y, -iPosition.z), 1.0);
    gl_Position = uCurrentProjectionMatrix * oViewPos;

    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(uCurrentModelViewMatrix))) * vec3(iNormal.x, iNormal.y, -iNormal.z));
    vec3 eyePosition = vec3(uCurrentModelViewMatrix * vec4(iPosition.x, iPosition.y, -iPosition.z, 1.0));

    oUv = (uCurrentTextureMatrix * vec4(iUv, 1.0, 1.0)).xy;

    oColor = iColor;

    if (uIsLight)
    {
        lightResult = getLightResult(eyeNormal, oViewPos);
    }
    else
    {
        lightResult = uMaterial.ambient;
    }
    oColor.rgb *= oColor.a;
}
```

The fragment shader is the following:

```
#version 150

in vec4 oViewPos;
in vec2 oUv;
in vec4 oColor;
in vec4 lightResult;

uniform bool uIsTexture;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uBrightness;
uniform float uOpacity;
uniform bool uIsFog;
uniform float uFogStart;
uniform float uFogEnd;
uniform vec3  uFogColor;
uniform int uMaterialFlags;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 textureColor = vec4(1.0);
    if(uIsTexture)
    {
        textureColor *= texture2D(uTexture, oUv);
        if((uMaterialFlags & 1) == 0 && (uMaterialFlags & 4) == 0)
        {
            //Material is not emissive and lighting is enabled, so multiply by brightness
            textureColor.rgb *= uBrightness;
        }
    }

    vec4 finalColor = vec4(((textureColor.rgb) * 1.0) + (oColor.rgb * (1 - textureColor.a)), textureColor.a * uOpacity);
    //Apply the lighting results *after* the final color has been calculated
    if((uMaterialFlags & 4) == 0)
    {
        //Lighting is enabled, so multiply by light result
        finalColor *= lightResult;
    }   
    // Fog
    float fogFactor = 1.0;

    if (uIsFog)
    {
        fogFactor *= clamp((uFogEnd - length(oViewPos)) / (uFogEnd - uFogStart), 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(mix(uFogColor, finalColor.rgb, fogFactor), finalColor.a);
}
```

Both can probably be optimised & there's a little redundant code where I've dumped stuff pertaining to additional lights etc. which we aren't using at the minute, but I'm trying to get the thing to work properly first!

(This forms part of a rather large open-source game; Happy to provide the Github link etc. if you feel like contributing a fix rather than trying to explain the multitude of ways in which I've probably gone wrong, or if you want a complete testing environment)

#### Code notes:

- The **uLight** uniform is set once at the start of the draw calls, using the same properties as the immediate mode code.
- MaterialFlags is a bitwise set of material properties; 1 is emissive, 4 draws the material unlit. (both work OK)
- I've tried both transforming the light position by the view matrix and not, neither produce correct results under all circumstances.
- All matrices etc. are shared between the two render paths, so it *shouldn't* be a case of bad matrix math.

Comment: *"This looks decent under most circumstances, and is the closest I've managed to get, but it isn't right at all."* - What's wrong with it.

Comment: In the legacy OpenGL light model, the light position and light direction is not transformed by the final model view matrix. The parameters are transformed by the current model view matrix, when they are set.

Comment: The trouble is that we've got 20 years of legacy content, which needs to look 'right' (Things originally started out on a prior program using a Direct3D retained mode renderer, then got ported to GL1.2).

Comment: So you want to implement a retro game, which looks like 20 years ago?

Comment: Two images from the same point here: https://imgur.com/a/kASNNrt     Note the shading on the wall to the right of the track and the track itself. It feels like a normal is reversed or something, but I've tried all sorts...

Comment: Not exactly, no. We've been hitting major issues with hi-polygon stuff and update speeds. Moving to a VAO based renderer and matrix math (as opposed to transforming entire models on a per-frame basis) is a lot faster, and hopefully will get us to a point where a mobile build can be considered eventually.